# meaning of "completely satisfied"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Sometimes people use the word "satisfied" in the following manner:

> I don't have what I want, but I have all that I need, so I am ***satisfied*** with everything in my life.

In the case above, is the person said to be "completely satisfied" with everything in his life?

If you are "completely satisfied" with your life, for instance, then you don't *want* anything more than what you have because you already *have everything you want*?

Comment: Try these words ***"content"*** and ***"satiated"***.

Comment: Bored and completely bored. Stupid and completely stupid. Fair and completely fair. Yellow and completely yellow. What does the dictionary tell you about *completely*?

Comment: If you think of "satisfied" as a threshold mental state in which the person finds his or her situation and circumstances acceptable without further changes, I don't think it is at all counterintuitive to imagine that there might be degrees of satisfaction that rise above that threshold state, perhaps culminating in a peak state of "completely satisfied." If my interpretation is reasonable, it follows that someone might be "satisfied" with a situation but not "completely satisfied" with it.

Answer (score 2):

"Completely satisfied" is more of a social indicator, meaning "there is nothing more I need *from you*".

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Nice answer. +1 from me.